# Bottom Nav Bar causing lag?

Tags: android

when I'm building my app, adding a bottom nav bar to the app causes big lag issues, anyone knows why that might be? I've tried BottomNavigationView, Toolbar, and even a simple LinearLayout with Image buttons. Setup is a MainActivity and fragments loaded into it thru bottom nav bar. When testing an app, there are lag issues, which all go away when removing the nav bar from the layout. Does anyone know why this might be?  NB using a BottomNavigationView with switch statement such as below made it even worse

```
public class FragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Fragment currentFragment;
    Fragment selectedFragment;


    public static final String TAG = FragmentActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_activity);


        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }

            // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
            SearchFragment searchFragment = new SearchFragment();

            currentFragment = searchFragment;

            // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an
            // Intent, pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments

            // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, currentFragment).commit();

            setBottomNavBar();
        }
    }

    public void setBottomNavBar() {

        Log.d(TAG, "setting up bar");

        LinearLayout bottomBar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ImageButton search = bottomBar.findViewById(R.id.search);
        search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectedFragment = new SearchFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment).commit();
            }
        });
        ImageButton user = bottomBar.findViewById(R.id.user);
        user.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectedFragment = new MyUserFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment).commit();

            }
        });
        ImageButton trending = bottomBar.findViewById(R.id.trending);
        trending.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TrendingMapTest.class);    //creating new intent, passing in the UserFeedActivity calling it
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        ImageButton upload = bottomBar.findViewById(R.id.upload);
        upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CameraAndGalleryActivity.class);    //creating new intent, passing in the UserFeedActivity calling it
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        ImageButton rewards = bottomBar.findViewById(R.id.rewards);
        rewards.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectedFragment = new RewardsFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment).commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

this is main activity xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:gravity="bottom">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/search_icon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/user"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/person_icon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/trending"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/forknife" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/upload"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/upload_icon" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/rewards"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/present_icon" />


    </LinearLayout> 

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: show your MainActivity

Comment: added relevant code

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:itemBackground="@color/bottamNav"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

menu/navigation_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
    android:title="@string/title_shop"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_watch"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart"
    android:title="@string/title_offer" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_download"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_wallet"
    android:title="@string/title_order" />

</menu>
```

---

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  BottomNavigationView navi;
  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    navi = findViewById(R.id.navigation);

    switchFragment(new HomeFragment());

    navi.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {
        Fragment fragment;
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.navigation_home) {
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            switchFragment(fragment);
            return true;
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.navigation_watch) {
            fragment = new WatchLaterFragment();
            switchFragment(fragment);
            return true;
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.navigation_download) {
            fragment = new DownloadsFragment();
            switchFragment(fragment);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
  }
  private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
  }
}
```

**update**

go to your Menifest file In your Activity just put HardwareAccelerated true to prevent lag of opening drawer

```
 <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"  
    >
    ...........
    ...........
 </activity>
```

Comment: Hi, this didnt work, unfortunatly this made the app even laggier

Comment: i don't think fragments are the issue, as every single one is laggy when adding a nav bar - when i remove the navbar there are zero issues

Comment: hi, i tried that, it definetly helped, but there's still some lag issues, its a little bit quicker than the original code - but still not running smooth